# DataTable - Why the first .Select() statement is very slow?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, performance, datatable

The following code is executed a few times during the runtime.

My problem is that the **first execution of that code is much slower than all the following executions**.
Even though 'strVariable' is assigned a different value for each execution.

```
Dim Rows() As DataRow = __DataSet.Tables("TableName").Select("IdL = '" & strVaraible & "'")
```

Is this the normal behavior and do you know a cure for it?

BackgroundInfo: The DataSet consists of 3 Tables. "TableName" is the biggest with 600000 Rows and 4 Columns. The other two are much smaller and have approximately 1000 Rows with 8 Columns.

Comment: It could be with that size of tables that some of the table is moved to your pagefile and when you run it the first time, it has to move it from your pagefile to your memory. Check your performance monitors for stuff like memory faults and/or IO usage.

Comment: Not sure if this could be your answer so I put here as a comment. But looking at the source code of the class Select (an internal class used by the DataTable class to resolve the Select method) you could see that the first time this class is called it executes numerous operation that are skipped in second calls. It builds an Index class and do other things regarding sorting [Reference Source Select.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/Select.cs) I can only suggest to not keep 600000 records in memory.

Comment: The relevant code is in the SelectRows method.

Comment: Steve, that is a great hint! I will go through the source code of the .Select() function and try to optimize my table so that this first-run-operations will be processed faster. Do you maybe know a way to skip that operations or to pre-run before the first .Select()? Sure, I could just run a 'fake' .Select() to preload it, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Work with the entity framework rather than datasets - these minimise (and automate) the number and size of calls to the data store